# CMake to handle F77 and F90 files differently

Tags: cmake, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to port our project from autotools to CMake and got stuck on fortran compiler settings. The project consists of C++, Fortran and Fortran90 pieces. In our autoconf/automake project we have simply defined FC and F77 together with corresponding flags like `FCFLAGS` and `FFLAGS`. But in CMake it seems to work a bit differently.

What I did so far:

```
project (blah-proj CXX Fortran)
... in ibm case ....
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-qfullpath -qinitauto -qnolm -qinit=f90ptr -qfree=f90 " )
```

and in the source directory `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
file (GLOB_RECURSE libblah_f_sources *.f90 *.f)
add_library (blah_f ${libblah_f_sources})
set_target_properties (blah_f PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)
```

With gfortran on linux it works fine as it's only one binary, but on AIX there are 2 different compilers called `xlf` and `xlf90`. Of course it doesn't work as  CMake tries to compile both `*.f` and `*.f90` files with same compiler.

Comment: Why would you want to treat them differently? Do you actually mean Fortran fixed form and Fortran free form sources (whatever the standard - that is normally irrelevant)? Even if yes, why bother distinguishing? I don't do that.

Comment: Now I can see a reason, it is some IBM nonsense... But still, doesn't xlf90 or even xlf2008 accept fixed form sources? It should if it is not completely crazy. I would just send everything to `xlf2008`.

Comment: The point is `.f` and `.f90` can be both Fortran 90 or both Fortran 2008, you have no way to know. The only way you know is that .f is fixed form and .f90 is free form.

Comment: Ok, then how to set different flags to different fortran files. For .f90 i would expect to set something like  "-qinit=f90ptr -qfree=f90" and for .f - "-qfixed=128". This was the difference in settings with autotools. And in fact yes, if i would use xlf - it compiles both, but those flags should be different for two extensions

Of course i can split the directories and do set_target_properties with different compiler options. But i would prefer a bit more elegant solution.

Comment: Why bother at all? If it compiles both why bother?

Comment: Hmm, good question. Because fortran is bad without some tuning. Especially if you work with older code from 30 years ago :)

The good question is why it is possible in automake and not possible in cmake which is supposed to be more advanced.

Comment: Define bad. If there is tuning necessary, than probably for individual files, not for source forms. if you add files using `*.f90 *.f` you can't expect individual treatment, can you?

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps it needs some different thinking. In the automake project we have same syntax. libblah_f_la_SOURCES defined and lists all .f and .f90 files. Automake then destingishes them all fine. All you need to do is to define two different vars like libblah_f_la_FFLAGS and libblah_f_la_FCFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem I got what I really wanted, but at least it solved the problem at the first approximation. I kept same structure but then I let compiler itself decide what kind of file it is. Of course I had to remove the version-dependent directives like -qfree=f90 or -qfixed=128 in the hope that compiler is smart enough to guess them from the file extension.

Comment: (not my answer, moved from the question to its proper place)